# Syncfusion flutter pdfviewer takes time while scrolling the pdf

Tags: pdf, syncfusion

Syncfusion flutter pdfviewer takes time while scrolling the pdf. It shows loading bar after scroll even I have downloaded the pdf in application directory and reading pdf from it using "syncfusion_flutter_pdfviewer: ^23.1.38", but it is taking time. As my pdf sizes are large like 100MB and more.[image: As in image it takes time to load after scrolling the pdf.] Please help to resolve this.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

We have used the native platform renderer, which is a plugin-based approach, to retrieve the PDF pages in our Flutter PdfViewer. This causes a delay of approximately 1 second when displaying the pages and performing page transitions. We only load the PDF pages based on virtualization. This means that initially, we render the pages based on the viewport constraints, and the rest of the pages are rendered on-demand while scrolling. Loading all the pages at once would increase loading time and memory consumption, depending on the size of the document, so we have avoided that behavior. We show a loading indicator to indicate that the pages are still loading.

Comment: I have the same problem. When I use PDF Kit with a native App on iOS the pages are all visible when paging/scrolling without loading indicator. It would be good to have some preload option to load the whole PDF document, to have no loading indicator or white pages anymore.